# A "reduce" function in Vim script

Tags: functional-programming, vim

Vim script has a few very basic functional programming facilities.

It has `map()` and `filter()`, but as far as I know it lacks a `reduce()` function. "[Reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)" reduces a collection of values to a single value.

Is there a way to create `reduce()` or emulate it somehow in Vim script? Is it possible to reduce a list of values, without writing an explicit loop, in a Vim script expression? As an example, is there a way to *reduce the first five positive integers over the addition operation*, as is par for the course in functional languages?

In JavaScript:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(x, y) { return x + y; });
15
```

In Clojure:

```
(reduce + (range 1 (inc 5)))
15
```

In Haskell:

```
foldl (+) 0 [1..5]
15
```

In J:

```
+/>:i.5
15
```

In Vim script: ...?

Comment: I now see that the ["Functional programming" chapter](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/39.html) in *Learn Vimscript the hard way* has this in the exercises section! "Implement `Reduced()`."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're expected to construct a string and then execute it (which I admit feels a bit clunky). The help (`:h E714`) gives this example:

```
:exe 'let sum = ' . join(nrlist, '+')
```

So in your case, where `nrlist` is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, it would construct the string `let sum = 1+2+3+4+5` and then execute it.

Alternatively, you can probably code up your own reduce function as there isn't one built in.

**Edit:**

I found [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/43GrmqvaxSA) on the vim_use Google Group (*How powerful is language build in vim compare with the language build in emacs?*, 25th Jan 2010) about functional programming in Vim, which included a couple of implementations of just such a reduce function.

The first, by Tom Link, is as follows:

```
function! Reduce(ffn, list) "{{{3
    if empty(a:list)
        return ''
    else
        let list = copy(a:list)
        let s:acc = remove(list, 0)
        let ffn = substitute(a:ffn, '\<v:acc\>', "s:acc", 'g')
        for val in list
            let s:acc = eval(substitute(ffn, '\<v:val\>', val, 'g'))
        endfor
        return s:acc
    endif
endf


echom Reduce("v:val + v:acc", [1, 2, 3, 4])
echom Reduce("v:val > v:acc ? v:val : v:acc", [1, 2, 3, 4])
echom Reduce("'v:val' < v:acc ? 'v:val' : v:acc", split("characters",
'\zs'))
```

The second, by Antony Scriven, is as follows:

```
fun Reduce(funcname, list)
    let F = function(a:funcname)
    let acc = a:list[0]
    for value in a:list[1:]
        let acc = F(acc, value)
    endfor
    return acc
endfun

fun Add(a,b)
    return a:a + a:b
endfun

fun Max(a,b)
    return a:a > a:b ? a:a : a:b
endfun

fun Min(a,b)
    return a:a < a:b ? a:a : a:b
endfun

let list = [1,2,3,4,5]
echo Reduce('Add', list)
echo Reduce('Max', list)
echo Reduce('Min', list)
```

Comment: Excellent info, thanks. You even found an example in the :help, I hadn't seen that. Well done!

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge In place of `execute 'let var = '.expr` I would really suggest using `let var = eval(expr)`. Also note that there are weak spots in both functions: 2. second uses `let F=function(a:funcname)`. While I would really *require* passing function reference to reduce implementation the weak spot is that once one defines function `F` (with `:function F()…endfunction` commands) this command will throw an error (variable name conflicts with existing function). The workaround is to use `let d={}|let d.F=function(a:funcname)`.

Comment: 1. First uses `s:acc` for unknown reason: just `acc` should work fine as well. Weak spot though is problems with constructing recursion (reduce call in reduce expression). I would not ever use `v:…` vars in such implementation, I would just use `…` (i.e. local variables) and no `substitute()` as it will spoil all `v:acc` strings, no matter whether or not they actually referer to variables (it is possible to have `v:acc` in a string). Also it is not obvious that using `s:v` in reduce expression will not work because `s:v` will be evaluated in context of the script that defined reduce function.

Comment: @glts Thus if one needs reduce I would suggest taking the second implementation, but remove `let F` and replace `F()` with `a:func` (and `a:funcname` with `a:func`): explicitly require function reference in arguments. To make it consistent with `sort()` (also `map()` and `filter()`) it would be better to swap `a:func` and `a:list` and add third optional argument that will hold a dictionary.

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, here are my variations on the theme, inspired by the answers that @MatthewStrawbridge linked.

The expression for the original example problem:

```
eval(join(range(1, 5), '+'))
```

A more general solution in the same vein, using `Add()`, where `a` is `range(1, 5)`:

```
eval(repeat('Add(',len(a)-1).a[0].','.join(a[1:],'),').')')
```

This constructs the string `"Add(Add(Add(Add(1,2),3),4),5)"`, and then `eval`s it. Fun!

Finally, `Reduce()`, which takes a Funcref and a list, and then reduces it in a loop using Vim's list "destructuring" syntax `[x, y; z]`. See `:h :let-unpack`.

```
function! Reduce(f, list)
  let [acc; tail] = a:list
  while !empty(tail)
    let [head; tail] = tail
    let acc = a:f(acc, head)
  endwhile
  return acc
endfunction
```

And this is how it's used:

```
:echo Reduce(function('Add'), range(1, 5))
15
```

Comment: Actually, the `let [head; tail] = tail` in the middle is *very* functional

Answer (score 0):

It's sad that it doesn't have a reduce function, here is mine

```
function s:reduce(acc, fn, args) abort
  let acc = a:acc
  for item in a:args
    let acc = a:fn(a:acc, item)
  endfor
  return acc
endfunc
```

Here is a sum function defined on terms of reduce

```
let Sum = {... -> s:reduce(0, {acc, arg -> acc + arg}, a:000)}
```