# Trouble when I try to set a macro expression

Tags: vim, vi

I have this file:

```
...
stuff
...

1 4 1
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 3 6
2 1 3
```

I'd like to do the sum of these 3 number and put the result as 4th number, and I want to do this for each line.

To do that, I do this:

```
qq # I register a macro with q letter
"ay # I move to the first line and first number (1) and save it into a
"by # I do the same with number 4
"cy # and for the last number of the line, number 1
esc+i # I go to insert mode and move to the position where I want the sum
ctrl+r+= # to go to the expression mode
ctrl+r+a + ctrl+r+b + ctrl+r+c # to take the numbers from the registers and sum them and I have the correct sum result pasted
esc # to exit from insert mode
q # to save the macro
```

If I use it with @q for the other lines, it does not work, but if I do it with the same line  that I used while recording the macro, it works, and pastes the same duplicate result:

```
1 4 11
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 3 6
2 1 3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an alternative, you can use the `:s` command to do this, for example: `:%s/\v^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/\=submatch(0).' '.(submatch(1)+submatch(2)+submatch(3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `"ay`, `"by`, and `"cy` do nothing on their own. `y` is an operator so it expects a motion. The proper commands would be `"ayiw`, `"byiw`, and `"cyiw`.
- I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve with `esc+i` but it is very unlikely to allow you to append anything after the last number.
- There are too many steps missing from your explanation anyway, so it's hard to debug your macro.

Here is how your recording should look, with every keystroke:

```
qq                                " start recording in @q
0                                 " move the cursor to the first column
"ayiw                             " yank the word under the cursor to @a
w                                 " move the cursor to the next word
"byiw                             " yank the word under the cursor to @b
w                                 " move the cursor to the next word
"cyiw                             " yank the word under the cursor to @c
A<Space>                          " append a space at the end of the line
<C-r>=<C-r>a+<C-r>b+<C-r>c<CR>    " insert the sum of @a, @b, and @c
<Esc>                             " leave insert mode
q                                 " stop recording
```

See `:help 0`, `help text-objects`, `:help w`, and `:help A`.

FWIW, here is a more scalable and predictable method:

```
qq
A <C-r>=getline('.')->split(' ')->reduce({ a, v -> a + v })<CR>
<Esc>
q
```

See `:help getline()`, `:help split()`, and `:help reduce()`.

Comment: I get results for `:help getline()` and `:help split()` (very interesting, thanks); but when I do `:help reduce()` I get a "Sorry, no help" message.  I'm using Vim 8.1 with patches 1-2269, 3612, 3625, 3669, 3741; "Huge version without GUI", usually on Windows 10 WSL.  Another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807349/a-reduce-function-in-vim-script makes me think `reduce()` is not in Vim, at least as of 2013.

Comment: @m_mlvx, we are in 2022. Current version is 8.2 and 9.0 is around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

Select the range of lines that you want to sum and run:

```
:'<,'>s/\v^(\d+ )(\d+ )(\d+)/\=submatch(1) . submatch(2) . submatch(3) . ' ' . (submatch(1) + submatch(2) + submatch(3))
```

NOTE: `'<,'>` it will be automatically placed by vim

Explanation:

```
\v ................. very magic search (avoid many backslashes)
^ .................. start of line
() ................. regex group
\d+ ................ one digit or more
\= ................. expression register
submatch(1) ........ repeats the first regex group
```